# Bs4 gets only a partial set of the html tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping html that contains the `<select>` tag inside a dropdown. I am looking for the selected item, i.e. the `<option>` tag that has the `selected` attribute.
As far as I understand, this code should do the trick:

```
   soup_1 = bs(result_1.content,'lxml')

    title = soup_1.find('select', {'id':'id_document'})
    title2 = title.findAll('option')
    for tit in title2:
        print(tit)
        if tit.has_attr('selected'):
            print("found")
            print(tit.getText())
```

Yet the list of `<options>` is very long (the console shows >5000 records) and bs/lxml seems to scan only 29 of them.

Is there a way to have it scan them all, or a more efficient way to perform the search? I have searched a bit around, but other than vague similarity to old bugs, I could not find a reason nor a solution.

I also tried doing a `find('select', {'selected':""})` but all records seem to satisfy the condition, even if only one effectively has that attribute inside the html. I could not either understand if searching through `find` checks all the entries or faces the same limitation.

Thanks

Edit:
Here's a portion/sample of the html I am trying to extract info from:

```
<select name="document" id="id_document" required>
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="294">Tutorials | Inkscape</option>
    <option value="241">Traduzione testo Mean - Taylor wift</option>
    <option value="243">http://www.angularjsbook.com/angular-basics/chapters/basics/</option>
    <option value="2521">script WLF 101 - Google Docs</option>
    <option value="290">LyX wiki | Layouts / Layouts</option>
    <option value="257">10Part2Chap7</option>
    <option value="296">Inkscape tutorial: Advanced | Inkscape</option>
    <option value="261">http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/Pages/about/faqs.aspx</option>
    <option value="273">Nuvolaverde - Home</option>
    <option value="240">BLACK EYED PEAS LYRICS - Where Is The Love?</option>
    <option value="2527">How to Start a Blog In The Most Cluttered Marketplace In History</option>
    <option value="2528">3 Simple Steps to Silencing Your Inner Critic – Matthew E. May – Medium</option>

    .... (some 5K more lines)

    <option value="4082">Lietuva - Prancūzija Tiesiogiai. Rugsėjo 7 d. 15:00 val. | TVPlay</option>
    <option value="4083">Google Calendar - settembre 2019</option>
    <option value="4084">Google Calendar - settembre 2019</option>
    <option value="4085" selected>Estructura de datos</option>
</select>
```

(Interesting discrepancy between the source code of the page, where the last line of the `option` list has just the attribute `selected`, and the console where the same attribute is shown as `selected=""`)

Comment: Can we see some of the content you are trying to scan?

Comment: Yes of course, added. I should have thought that guessing about the html would have been a bit hard. Is that enough to understand @MatthewGaiser?

Comment: That seems to explain it nicely.

Comment: How are you handling the beautifulsoup import?

Comment: Nvm, solved that.

Comment: Can you send me the page you are trying to scan?

Comment: No, it's behind a login sorry :/
Can I add something to make it clearer?

Comment: I am mostly trying to replicate the error and its not happening with the 30 or so you gave me.

Comment: Ok, I created a pastebin with some 600 hundred of those records, and the last one is again the selected one: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/5OkY77fe6LerI15ln5F1vQ
Let me know if it helps

Comment: No problems finding it. I moved it around in the content as well. It found selected every time and very quickly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199346/discussion-between-giampaolo-ferradini-and-matthew-gaiser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We verified that the code works for the purposes of identifying the selected option, even with the high quantity of options, which were entered as a string for testing purposes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content =''' <String of text sent via pastebin here>
 '''
soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
title = soup_1.find('select', {'id': 'id_document'})
title2 = title.findAll('option')
for tit in title2:
    if tit.has_attr('selected'):
        print("found")
        print(tit.getText())
```

In our chat, we determined that the problem is likely in scraping the tags from the website rather than the processing of the data. Anyone else who stumbles upon this should check that their `request.content` or `content` actually contains the information which they wish to scrape.

Comment: you could condense all that into soup.select_one('#id_document [selected]').text